# Xcode 9.4 highlighting issues on Mojave

Tags: c++, macos-mojave, xcode9.4, audacity

I am currently working on customising audacity in Xcode9.4.
I work on MacOS Mojave so I had to use Xcode9.4 instead of Xcode 10 in order to even build Audacity. 
However in Xcode 9.4 the highlighting seems very broken.
In the existing header files of the project the highlighting seems to work from time to time when modifying files. If I try to include new header files the highlighting completely fails. Not even basic keywords like std are highlighted.

I already tried deleting derived data and cleaning the project, but none of these worked.

Anyone got any idea to fix this highlighting issue ?